# Is polynomial function continuous in all topologies?

Tags: general-topology

1.Intuitively, no. But I can't think of examples.

2.In the Topology Book by GF Simmons, before introducing to stone Weierstrass theorem it is stated, that it is meaningless to speak of polynomials on $X$. And hence they have been introduced as subalgebra generated by $\{1,x\}$. Why can't we just say that they are vector spaces formed by basis $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots\}$?

Comment: In all topologies?  No.  For example, consider the really silly topology $\{ \emptyset, [0,1], \mathbb{R} \}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ (NB:  this is closed under unions and finite intersections, and contains the emptyset and $\mathbb{R}$, so it is a topology).  Most polynomial functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ will not be continuous with respect to this topology.

Comment: Hi, welcome on the MathSE! Note, this site supports Latex, just write `$5\cdot 5$` and you get $5\cdot 5$.

Comment: @JohnMa That's not true. Any function from a trivial topological space to itself is continuous.

Comment: There are several things you could mean by "polynomial function" here. What is the domain and codomain? If they're the same, are you putting the same topology on both?

Comment: @XanderHenderson . Or even the topology $T=\{\emptyset, \{0\}, \Bbb R\}$ and $p(x)=x-x^2$, because $p^{-1}\{0\}=\{0,1\}\not \in T.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Indeed, any essentially trivial topology (i.e. the trivial topology plus set) provides a counter-example.  I don't know why a closed interval was the first thing that came to my mind.  Your example is much nicer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general result which answers your first question:

- **Fact**: Suppose $f:X\rightarrow X$. Then the following are equivalent:

  - $f$ is either the identity function or is constant.
  - For every topology $\tau$ on $X$, $f$ as a map from $(X,\tau)$ to $(X,\tau)$ is continuous. *(Note that we use the the same topology on the domain and the codomain; this is crucial, since e.g. if $X$ has at least two elements then the identity map on $X$ is **not** continuous with respect to the indiscrete topology on the domain and the discrete topology on the codomain.)*

*Proof*: Clearly if $f$ is either the identity or constant then $f$ is continuous with respect to every topology on $X$. Conversely, suppose there are $x, y\in X$ such that $f(x)\not=x$ and $f(y)\not=f(x)$ *(note that this happens exactly when $f$ is neither the identity nor constant)*. Consider the topology $$\tau=\{X,\emptyset,\{f(x)\}\}.$$ The set $A=\{f^{-1}(\{f(x)\})\}$ contains $x$ *(so $A\not=\emptyset$)* and $x\not=f(x)$ *(so $A\not=\{f(x)\}$)* and doesn't contain $y$  *(so $A\not=X$)*; this means $A$ isn't open in the $\tau$ sense. But $A$ is the $f$-preimage of a set which is open in the $\tau$ sense, so $f$ is **not** continuous with respect to $\tau$. $\quad\quad\Box$